How to run code at the start of my flutter app and notify ChangeNotifier accordingly when the operation is finish?
I have a flutter app that use the provider package to represent state.
At the start of my app I want to run some operations and set the state of my application accordingly (when the operation are finished)
Here is what I would like to do:
class A extends ChangeNotifier {
  void computute(Data data) {
  ...
  }
...
}

class B  extends ChangeNotifier {
  B(){
    var data = _runOperations();
    _data = data.forB; // set my own state
    var a = Provider.of<A>(context); // not possible
    a.compute(data.forA); // notify another provider that my operations have finish and to change state accordingly
  }
...

}

the issue I have here is that there is no build context so I can't get access to other ChangeNotifier.
How to run code at the start of my flutter app and notify ChangeNotifier accordingly when the operation is finish?

You could create an init(BuildContext context) function in your ChangeNotifier class then call it in your root widget InitState() after changing it to a StatefulWidget
Also don't forget to call notifyListeners() in your ChangeNotifier functions.
An other solution would be to set a navigatorKey in your MaterialApp :
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

see : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/navigatorKey.html
You could get the context from everywhere you want with :
navigatorKey.currentContext

Hope it helped you
